# How do I determine which version of Python I'm using?

Tags: python3

I'm using the MySQL Workbench to run MySQL 5.7 and I have Python installed.

Comment: @AkhilVarma That only show python 2 on Ubuntu.

Comment: @AkhilVarma because Ubuntu uses multiple versions. python refers to python2, python3 to python3.

Comment: ....but that only shows the version of 3.

Comment: he asked question for python3 , that's why..@JacobVlijm. anyway your answer was optimum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55221/discussion-between-akhil-varma-and-jacob-vlijm).

Answer (score 3):

Run the following commands and whichever gives an output is the version you have:

- Python 2: `python --version`
- Python 3: `python3 --version`

Note: You can have both installed and used independently by simply adding the *shebang* to the top of the Python script to indicate which you want to use. Example:

```
python 2 script: #!/usr/bin/python
python 3 script: #!/usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on Babun (Cygwin fork) and when I type `python --version` it displays the version.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.8
```

On a sidenote:

if you have different versions of Python installed, you can switch between them using a shell alias (add to your `.bashrc`) for example:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

Please do use this carefully, as it might break things. Switching between 2.6 and 2.7 should normally work.

Comment: If you mean switch between 2 and 3, this is an extremely bad idea. Please clarify.